# Permissions vs. EffectiveRights

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using the calendar.Permissions to find out which rights the logged-in person has on another.

```
var myEmail = GetPrimaryMailForIdentity(User.Identity);
...
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(serviceAccountName, serviceAccountPass);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(toEmail);
...
var calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service,WellKnownFolderName.Calendar)
foreach (var permission in calendar.Permissions) {
    if(permission.UserId.PrimarySmtpAddress == myEmail) {
        if(permission.ReadItems == FolderPermissionReadAccess.TimeOnly) permission = "TimeOnly";
        ...
    }
}
```

This only gives me some of the various rights one person can have on another mailbox, since there could also be a FullAccess rule, or the mailbox could be that of a resource he owns/manages. So I could also impersonate the user for whom to get the permission, and check the effective rights:

```
var myEmail = GetPrimaryMailForIdentity(User.Identity);
...
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(serviceAccountName, serviceAccountPass);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(toEmail);
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, myEmail);
...
var calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service,WellKnownFolderName.Calendar)
var permissions = calendar.EffectiveRights;
if(permissions.HasFlag(EffectiveRights.Read) {
    permission = "TimeOnly"; // TODO
}
```

But how can I find out WHAT he is allowed to read - all details, or only time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FolderPermissionReadAccess enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folderpermissionreadaccess(v=exchg.80).aspx) seems to be what you're looking for. EffectiveRights doesn't expose that level of information.